# Show that $h(z):=\int_X f(z,t) d\mu(t)$ is holomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be a $\sigma-$finite measure on some measure space $X$, and $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ be a domain. Assume that

1. the mapping $(z,t)\in \Omega \times X \rightarrow f(z,t)\in \mathbb{C}$ is measurable
2. for fixed $t \in X$, the function $z \mapsto f(z,t)$ holomorphic and
3. for every compact set $K \subseteq \Omega$,

$\int_X sup_{z \in K} |f(z,t)| d\mu(t) $ is finite

Show that the function $h(z):=\int_X f(z,t) d\mu(t)$ is holomorphic in $\Omega$

Approach:
My Idea would be to use Moreas Theorem.
Thus I need to show that for every closed piecewise $C^1$ curve
$\int_{\gamma}h(z)dz=0$.

$\int_{\gamma}h(z)dz=\int_{\gamma}\int_X f(z,t) d\mu(t)dz$

If I could change the order of Integration I would get
$\int_{\gamma}h(z)dz=\int_X \int_{\gamma} f(z,t) dz d\mu(t)$.
Then $\int_{\gamma} f(z,t) dz$ is the integral of a holomorphic function since $t$ is fixed in this case.
By Cauchy Theorem I would get $\int_{\gamma} f(z,t) dz=0$, and thus $\int_X 0 d\mu(t)=0$.

My main problem seems to be that I don't know how to argue that I can interchange both integrals. I assume it has to do with 3).

Question: Is my approach even correct? If yes, what is the reason to interchange the integrals?

Comment: Your approach is right, but you only need to look at small loops that bound a closed disk in $\Omega$. Do you know about [Fubini's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem)?

Comment: @Didier I know about Fubini, but how does it help to look at small loops that bound a closed disk?

Comment: Because 1) being holomorphic is local, so it suffices to show it on every small disk
2) every small closed disk is compact. (Some loop may not bound a compact domain in $\Omega$, think of $\Omega = \Bbb C^*$ and the unit circle) 3) Morera's Theorem is valid on simply connected domains only, and you don't have this assumption for $\Omega$

Comment: @Didier What exactly does "small loop" mean? Does is it mean $\partial B(\epsilon,a)$?

Comment: I mean a loop enclosed in a simply connected subdomain of $\Omega$

Comment: The complex integral $\int_\gamma g(z)dz$ can be written as $\int_a^b g(\gamma(s))\gamma'(s)ds$, where $\gamma:[a,b]\to \Omega$ is a parametrization. This is a Riemann integral, and so a Lebesgue one for which you can use the usual Fubini's theorem if the hypotheses are satisfied.

Comment: @Didier ok, so if $\gamma$ small loop, there exists some closed disk $\overline{D}$ that is bounded by this loop. Now 3) states that $\int_X \sup_{z \in \overline{D}} |f(z,t)| d\mu(t)dz <\infty$, since $\overline{D}$ is compact. Since $\overline D$ was arbitrary, we get that $\int_{\gamma} \int_X |f(z,t)| d\mu(t) dz < \infty$. Thus one can change the order of integration by Fubini. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $p\in \Omega$, and let $\varepsilon>0$ be small enough so that $B(p,\varepsilon) \subset \Omega$.
$\DeclareMathOperator{\d}{d} \newcommand{\dx}{\d\!}$
Let us show that $h$ is holomorphic on $B(p,\varepsilon)$.
Since $B(p,\varepsilon)$ is simply connected, by Morera's it suffices to show that for every piecewise differentiable closed curve $\gamma$ in $B(p,\varepsilon)$, $\int_\gamma h(z)\dx z = 0$.

Let $\gamma\colon [a,b] \to B(p,\varepsilon)$ be such a closed curve, and up to a reparametrization, assume that $|\gamma'(s)|=1$ for all $s$.
Since $|f(\gamma(s),t)\gamma'(s)| = |f(\gamma(s),t)| \geqslant 0$ on $B(p,\varepsilon)\times X$, we have
\begin{align}
\int_{[a,b]} \int_X |f(\gamma(s),t)\gamma'(s)|\dx\mu(t)\dx s
&= \int_X\int_{[a,b]} |f(\gamma(s),t)|\dx s\dx\mu(t) \\
&\leqslant (b-a)\int_X \sup_{z\in \gamma([a,b])} |f(z,t)|\dx\mu(t) \\
& <+ \infty
\end{align}
by the third assumption.
It follows by Fubini's Theorem that
\begin{align}
\int_{[a,b]} \int_X f(\gamma(s),t)\gamma'(s)\dx\mu(t)\dx s
& =  \int_X \int_{[a,b]} f(\gamma(s),t)\gamma'(s)\dx s\dx\mu(t) \\
&= \int_X \int_{\gamma}f(z,t)\dx z \dx\mu(t) \\
&= \int_X 0 \dx\mu(t) \\
&= 0,
\end{align}
the last equality being true since $f(\cdot,t)$ is holomorphic on $B(p,\varepsilon)$ which is simply connected.
Hence, $\int_\gamma h(z)\dx z = 0$.
This being true for all $\gamma$, $h$ is holomorphic on $B(p,\varepsilon)$.
In particular, $h$ is holomorphic at $p$.
This being true for all $p \in \Omega$, $h$ is holomorphic on $\Omega$.